# Password validation for javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I have a password validation function that I'm having trouble with. I have it working so that the user is immediately warned when the passwords don't match. However, I also want it to state that the password should have letters and numbers, and it can't be less than 6 characters. No matter what way I do it it won't work. Here is what I have that works so i just need help adding the rest. Thanks

```
<head>
function checkpass(pass1,pass2)
{
    pass1=document.getElementById("txtpassword").value;
pass2=document.getElementById("txtpassword2").value;

    if (pass1 != pass2)
    {
    alert ("Passwords must match");
    }
    }
</head>
<body>
<form action="Home.html" method="post" name="form1" onsubmit="Display()">
  <table bgcolor="white" width="700" border="0" align="center">
  <col width="200">
  <col width="200">


    <tr>
    <th colspan = "2" align = "center" bgcolor="grey"> Fill the form to sign up. </th>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Forename</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td><label>
         <input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname" class="info" required>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="txtsurname" id="txtsurname" class="info" required />
      </label></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td> Create Username</td>
    <td> Birthday</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label>
    <input type="text" name="txtusername" id="txtusername" class="info" required/>
    </label></td>




    <td><select name="DOBMonth" required>
<option value="">    Month  </option>
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
<option value="April">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">June</option>
<option value="July">July</option>
<option value="August">August</option>
<option value="September">September</option>
<option value="October">October</option>
<option value="November">November</option>
<option value="December">December</option>
</select>

<select name="DOBDay" required>
    <option value="">   Day  </option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<select name="DOBYear" required>
    <option value=""> Year </option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
    <option value="2008">2008</option>
    <option value="2007">2007</option>
    <option value="2006">2006</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
    <option value="2003">2003</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="1999">1998</option>
    <option value="1998">1998</option>
    <option value="1997">1997</option>
    <option value="1996">1996</option>
    <option value="1995">1995</option>
    <option value="1994">1994</option>
    <option value="1993">1993</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="1989">1989</option>
    <option value="1988">1988</option>
    <option value="1987">1987</option>
    <option value="1986">1986</option>
    <option value="1985">1985</option>
    <option value="1984">1984</option>
    <option value="1983">1983</option>
    <option value="1982">1982</option>
    <option value="1981">1981</option>
    <option value="1980">1980</option>
    <option value="1979">1979</option>
    <option value="1978">1978</option>
    <option value="1977">1977</option>
    <option value="1976">1976</option>
    <option value="1975">1975</option>
    <option value="1974">1974</option>
    <option value="1973">1973</option>
    <option value="1972">1972</option>
    <option value="1971">1971</option>
    <option value="1970">1970</option>
    <option value="1969">1969</option>
    <option value="1968">1968</option>
    <option value="1967">1967</option>
    <option value="1966">1966</option>
    <option value="1965">1965</option>
    <option value="1964">1964</option>
    <option value="1963">1963</option>
    <option value="1962">1962</option>
    <option value="1961">1961</option>
    <option value="1960">1960</option>
    <option value="1959">1959</option>
    <option value="1958">1958</option>
    <option value="1957">1957</option>
    <option value="1956">1956</option>
    <option value="1955">1955</option>
    <option value="1954">1954</option>
    <option value="1953">1953</option>
    <option value="1952">1952</option>
    <option value="1951">1951</option>
    <option value="1950">1950</option>
    <option value="1949">1949</option>
    <option value="1948">1948</option>
    <option value="1947">1947</option>
</select>




    <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td>Confirm Email</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" class="info" onchange="ValidateEmail(txtemail)" required />
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="txtemail2" id="txtemail2" class="info" onchange="ValidateEmail2(txtemail2)" required/>
      </label></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td>Confirm Pasword</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input type="password" name="txtpassword" id="txtpassword" class="info" required/>
      <td><label>
        <input type="password" name="txtpassword2" id="txtpassword2" class="info" required/ onchange="checkpass(txtpassword,txtpassword2)">
      </label></td>
    </tr>


    <td colspan="2" style="font-size:12px">**Passwords must be at least 8 characters in length.</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>


      <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="terms" id="terms" required/>
          I agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
        </td></tr>
        <br><br><br>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="notify" value="notify" id="notify" />
          I want to receive notifications by text/email about new products in stock.</label>
          </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="submit" name="Login" id="Login" value="Login"/>
    </label></td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Reset" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: js code without using <script> tag?

Comment: It's in it I just copied out the only function that I'm talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code

```
function checkpass() {
  var pass1=document.getElementById("txtpassword").value;
  var pass2=document.getElementById("txtpassword2").value;

  if (pass1 !== pass2) {
    alert ("Passwords must match");
  } else if (pass1.length < 6) {
     // too short
  } else if (!/[0-9]/.test(pass1)) {
     // no digit
  } else if (!/[A-Za-z]/.test(pass1)) {
    // no character
  } else {
    return true; // return true when password matched rules
  }
  return false; // false otherwise
}
```